# is this a simplicial model category?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, model-categories, topos-theory

A basic result in the theory of model categories is that simplicial sets form a simplicial model category. The same is true for simplicial $k$-algebras. I have two questions related to this. One involves defining model categories via gluing and the second involves defining model categories via functor of points. I have no idea if these questions are extremely easy or difficult. I am sure they display my lack of knowledge when it comes to model categories.

Consider the category $\mathbb{V}_k$ of all separated schemes of finite type over a field $k$ along with a grothendieck topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $\mathbb{V}_k$.

Question A) Is the simplicial cateogry $s\mathbb{V}_k$ of $\mathbb{V}_k$ a simplicial model category (or even just a model category)?

Question B) Let $\mathbb{S}_k$ be the category formed by subfunctors of representable functors from $\mathbb{V}_k \to Sets$. Let $s\mathbb{S}_k$ be the simplicial category of $\mathbb{S}_k$. Is $s\mathbb{S}_k$ a simplicial model category?

Comment: Any category with finite (or small, to taste) limits and colimits is automatically a model category in a trivial way. You should at least specify what kind of weak equivalences you wish to consider.

Comment: "Is $X$ a model category" is a type error. Being a model category is a structure, not a property.

Comment: The weak equivalences should be the ones induced from the weak equivalences in the category of simplicial $k$-algebras.

Comment: Regarding A you might have a look at Quillen's Homotopical Algebra, Section II.4. There are stated general conditions when simplicial objects form a simplicial model category.

Comment: Prof. Meier: Thanks! I will try to prove that it satisfies these conditions.

Comment: @AndrewStout Then there's a different problem: a simplicial $k$-algebra regarded geometrically is a _cosimplicial_ affine $k$-scheme.

Comment: i understand, but that is not a problem. the definitions of a model category are symmetric.

Comment: I believe Question B is answered affirmatively by work of Jaurdine in "intermediate model structures on simplicial presheaves."

Comment: The definition of model category may be symmetric, but the existence of model structures is far from symmetric. Unlike the case of simplicial algebras, it's far from obvious what weak equivalences of simplicial schemes should be, even if we restrict to the affine case (i.e. _cosimplicial_ algebras).

Comment: Again, I am interested in defining weak equivalence coming from the dual of the weak equivalences in simplicial algebras. Actually, I think I have answered my question at any rate ala Jardine's work. Thanks for your help.